# cannot modify .csproj files using build auto with tfs 13

Tags: build, workflow, tfsbuild, workflow-activity

I created a workflow activity named `EditCsproj` which is a C# class that I added to my build template.  I put it right after the *`Initialize Workspace`* step.

[image]

This workflow has to get all *`.csproj`* files in the directory path that I provide as a parameter and it has to modify them.

But for each files, I have the following error :

> *Access to the path 'file.csproj' is denied.*

I run Visual Studio with Administrator rights and I already changed the *`msbuild multi-proc`* property to false.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Did you check if the .csproj files are read-only?

Comment: BTW would be interesting to have a clue on what you are trying to achieve, as sometime working at the MSBuild level is simpler and more flexible than customizing the workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a classic gotcha. You need to remove the read-only flag from the files before editing them.