# Could not write destination file: Access to path 'd:\a\src\...\Web.config' is denied

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a tfs project on visual studio online and created a build definition to compile this project. The project uses web config transformation. The build will be executed from the visual studio online hosted build controller and it fails because of the following error:

Could not write destination file: Access to path 'd:\a\src...\Web.config' is denied.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does your build require administrative privileges for any of the tasks? Hosted build controller does not support this at the moment.

Comment: After the build it needs to transform the web.base.config and write the file web.config on the hosted build controller. I don't know if this requires administrative privileges, but it needs write permissions for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the classic problem of read-only files (see [cannot modify .csproj files using build auto with tfs 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392615/cannot-modify-csproj-files-using-build-auto-with-tfs-13/30393540#30393540)). Run a pre-build Powershell script that removes the attribute, something like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.config -Recurse | foreach {
    if ($_.IsReadOnly) { $_.IsReadOnly = $false }
}
```